# How to fix the infinite loop in Skiena's dfs (depth first search) implementation c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, infinite-loop, depth-first-search

I am running into infinite loop even after including errata changes in Skiena's dfs implementation from "The Algorithm Design Manual" book by Steven Skiena 2nd edition and I'd like to know how to fix it.
The reason seems quite obvious and applies to any undirected graph which makes me think may be I am doing it wrong but just cant figure out.

Take any undirected graph (or the one on pg171 if you have the book), say there is an edge (1,6). In the adjacency list alist[6] will have a node for 1 and alist[1] will have node for 6. Starting DFS for vertex = 1 (calling dfs(1)), it first discovers 6 and sets parent[6]=1. Recursive call dfs(6) then wants to discover 1 but 1 is already discovered. This causes first if condition in the while loop to become false

```
if (!discovered[y]) )
```

and therefore does not set parent[1].

1 is not processed yet and parent[6] is 1 (i-e y) as set in previous iteration therefore else if condition in the while loop is also false.

```
else if (((!processed[y]) && (parents[v] != y)) || (directed))
```

Since we do not reset the pointer p to the next node in the linked list because of else conditiona going false, it goes in an infinite loop

```
while (p != nullptr)
```

So basically it gets stuck at processing the first edge (1,6) and (6,1) and this should happen with any undirected graph. What is the fix for this infinite loop? or I am doing something wrong here different than skiena implementation?

Heres the minimum compilable and runnable code reproducing the infinite loop, including the main()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

const int MAX_VERTICES = 10000;
struct EdgeNode {
private:
    int y{ -1 };
    EdgeNode* next{ nullptr };
public: 
    EdgeNode(int _y,  EdgeNode* _next) : y{ _y }, next{ _next }{}
    EdgeNode(int _y) : y{ _y }, next{ nullptr}{}
    const int getY() const { return y; } ;
    const EdgeNode* const getNext() const { return next; };
    
};

class Graph {
    EdgeNode* edges[MAX_VERTICES]{ nullptr };
    int degree[MAX_VERTICES]{ 0 };
    int totalVertices{ 0 };
    int totalEdges{ 0 };    
    bool directed{ false };
    bool processed[MAX_VERTICES]{ false };
    bool discovered[MAX_VERTICES]{ false };
    bool finished = false;
    int parents[MAX_VERTICES];
    void initializeSearch() {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VERTICES; i++)
        {
            parents[i] = -1;
            processed[i] = false;
            discovered[i] = false;
        }
        finished = false;
    }
public:
    int Vertices() const    {return totalVertices; }
    int Edges() const { return totalEdges; }
    const EdgeNode* getEdge(int x) const {
        if (x > MAX_VERTICES)  return nullptr;
        return edges[x];
    }
    bool insertEdge(int x, int y) { return insertEdge(x, y,  false); }
    bool insertEdge(int x, int y,  bool _directed) {
        if (x > MAX_VERTICES) { std::cout << std::endl << "Unable to insert edge. Max vertices allowed:" << MAX_VERTICES; return false; }
        EdgeNode* temp = new EdgeNode(y,  edges[x]);
        if (degree[x] == 0) totalVertices++;
        edges[x] = temp;
        degree[x]++;
        totalEdges++;
        if (!_directed) {
            insertEdge(y, x,  true);
        }
        return true;
    }
        void process_vertex_late(int vertex) {}
        void process_vertex_early(int vertex) {std::cout << std::endl << "Processing Vertex: " << vertex;}
    void process_edge_dfs(int x, int y) {       
        std::cout << std::endl << "\tProcessing Edge(" << x << "," << y << ")";
        if (discovered[y] && (parents[x] != y)) {
            std::cout << std::endl << "Cycle(" << x << "," << y << ")";
            std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
            finished = true;
        }
    }
        void dfs1(int start) {
        initializeSearch();
        dfs(start, false);
    }
    void dfs(int v, bool print) {
        const EdgeNode* p;
        int y;
        if (finished) 
            return;
        discovered[v] = true;
        process_vertex_early(v);
        p = getEdge(v);
        while (p != nullptr) {
            y = p->getY();
            if (!discovered[y]) {
                parents[y] = v;
                process_edge_dfs(v, y);
                dfs(y, false);
            }
            else if (((!processed[y]) && (parents[v] != y)) || (directed))
            {
                process_edge_dfs(v, y);
                if (finished) 
                    return;
                p = p->getNext();
            }
        }
        process_vertex_late(v);
        processed[v] = true;
    }
    
};
int main()
{
    Graph graph;    
    graph.insertEdge(1, 2);
    graph.insertEdge(1, 5);
    graph.insertEdge(1, 6);
    graph.insertEdge(2, 5);
    graph.insertEdge(2, 3);
    graph.insertEdge(3, 4);    
    graph.insertEdge(4, 5);
    graph.dfs1(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *What is the fix for this infinite loop?* -- Change your plan and recode your program.  If the program is faulty, then wouldn't you know what to change to get it to follow the plan you had in mind?

Comment: If I knew how to fix the dfs implementation then why would I ask?

Comment: One fix is to add this just before while loop exit, but I dont know if it will be still a valid dfs implementation.                  p = p->getNext();

Comment: So why don't you implement your fix and see if it works?

Comment: Also, you're assuming that we know what (or who) "Skiena" is, or what is on page 107 of a particular book.  If you're going to take code and change it, you're responsible to know 100% what that code does, how it works, and what implications any changes you will make will have.  Otherwise it will become a form of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), and that is not a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find your answer.

I have the second edition of the book and I see what is your mistake.

You wrote

```
else if (((!processed[y]) && (parents[v] != y)) || (directed))
{
                process_edge_dfs(v, y);
                if (finished) 
                    return;
                p = p->getNext();
}
```

The correct implementation is :

```
else if (((!processed[y]) && (parents[v] != y)) || (directed))
   process_edge_dfs(v, y);

if (finished) return;
p = p->getNext();
...
```

In my edition, the code is on two pages and the alignment is not the same.
it's very confusing.